# Как на PHP сделать замену текста?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как на PHP сделать замену текста `**bold**` на `<b>bold</b>`, `__underline__` на `<u>underline</u>` и `--str--` на  `<strike>str</strike>`

То есть есть текст, который попадает на обработку в функцию, и если найдены пользовательские спецсимволы, то мы форматируем его как показано выше.

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать?

Comment: Markdown используйте. Например такой парсер http://parsedown.org/

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью preg_replace()

```
$str = 'здравствуйте, как на php можно из текста bold сделать **bold** из underline сделать __underline__ и из str сделать --str--**';

$patt = ['~\*\*([^*]+)\*\*~','~__([^_]+)__~', '~--([^-]+)--~'];
$repl = ['<b>$1</b>', '<u>$1</u>', '<strike>$1</strike>'];
$str = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: А при `здравствуйте, как на php можно из текста bold сделать **bold** из underline сделать __underline__ и из str сделать  --str--**` что получите?

Comment: @Visman, подправил шаблон. Спасибо.